# NoMethodError thrown when trying to use controller variables in js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my assets, I have a file called `maps.js.erb`, basically with only the following (debugging) content:

```
alert("<%= @map.width %>");
```

This JS file is loaded through the `show.html.erb` view belonging to maps.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
<h1><%= @map.title %></h1>
…
```

The HTML file itself shows the map's title, e.g. when browsing to `/maps/1/`, since `@map` is defined in the controller. However, as soon as I include the JS file, I get the following error:

> #### NoMethodError in Maps#show
>
> Showing `…/app/views/maps/show.html.erb` where line #1 raised:
>
> undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass
>     (in `…/app/assets/javascripts/maps.js.erb`)

- Why is `@map` not available in the `js.erb` file?
- How else can I access this instance variable defined in my controller?

Comment: you'd rather debug with `alert("<%= @map.width %>");
`

Comment: You're right, but it doesn't really matter in the context of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryan Bates did a screencast right on that topic - you might wanna check it out:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript

---

In the `html.erb` file, you can define the variables:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  window.productsURL = "<%=j products_url %>";
  window.products = <%=raw Product.limit(10).to_json %>;
<% end %>
```

Comment: @slhck: thanks for updating my question. Still, I don't think that this is the way to go, since you changed from _unobtrusive JavaScript_ to _inline JavaScript_, which I don't consider a best practice. You might want to discuss this in the chat with me at some point.

Comment: I really just need a few variables passed, so it's an acceptable solution for me. Do you have a nicer idea that doesn't involve too much overhead?

Comment: @slhck: I'll think about it and let you know

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have @map.title evaluated in a common js file, because that file is generated and served once, before later invokations of the controller, and then cached.

However, you can have javascript in your HTML page.  That javascript can be generated with a constant value supplied by <%= @map.title %>.

Put the javascript in a partial, and render it in a  tag in your page.

I have seen Bank of America do this in their web site.  They generate all the account transactions in a javascript array on the page.

Comment: But why would I even be able to use ERB in a JS file if not to access variables? Any other good use case for that?

Comment: I cannot defend that ERB for a JS file would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use `escape_javascript()`.

Comment: How? Where? Can you elaborate? Maybe give an example?